# Discriminant with Inequalities

Tags: isabelle

I'm quite new using Isabelle. I tried to find lemma to solve this

```
lemma  
  fixes x y z k :: real
  assumes "x ≠ 0"
and "⋀k. (x*(k)⇧2 + y*k + z) ≥0"
shows "discrim x y z ≤ 0"
```

using sledgehammer give me no results. I found Quadratic_Discriminant theory but there is not lemma proved for inequalities. So does it proved in Isabelle or not yet?

Comment: The statement as you have written it down is false. Quickcheck already gives you a counterexample: `k = x = y -1` and `z = 0`, which fulfils the assumptions but yields `discrim x y z = 1`. What did you actually mean? Did you mean something like `∀k. x*k^2 + y*k + z ≥ 0` in the assumptions?

Comment: Sorry, I did a mistak, It should be "discrim x y z ≥ 0"

Comment: That doesn't hold either. This time, the counterexample is `x = z = 1` and `y = k = -1`. Quickcheck tells you this automatically when you state the goal.

Comment: yes you abslutly right, k should be under quantifier constraint. So the assumption should be ⋀k. x*k^2 + y*k + z ≥ 0 and the prove should discrim x y z ≤ 0 . The problem is that I proved this lemma fixes x y z k :: real assumes "x ≠ 0" and "⋀k. (x*(k)⇧2 + y*k + z) >0" shows "discrim x y z ≤ 0" by (metis (full_types) assms(1) assms(2) discriminant_pos_ex less_irrefl not_le) but this is for greater and I should have it for greated than or equal in the assumption...please could you help

Comment: This lemma looks correct to me, but it has not been proven in Isabelle yet. If you want a proof: How would you prove this on pen and paper?

Comment: I'm working on it now and I'm sure that I will solve it as I found a theorem support it in a text book. Thanks so much Manuel for help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this but I'm not sure if its correct:

```
lemma  
  fixes a b c x :: real
  fixes p:: "real⇒real"
  assumes a:"a ≠ 0"
  and ag:"a>0"
  and p: "⋀x.  p(x) ≥0"
  and x:"⋀x. x= -(b/(2*a))"
and eq:"⋀x. p(x) = (a*(x)⇧2 + b*x + c)"
shows " discrim a b c ≤ 0" using assms 
by metis
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but I think the assumption `x:"⋀x. x= -(b/(2*a))"` shouldn't be as assumption but should be proved. Do you agree with me in this?

Comment: I'm not sure as I told you before, I just tried this lemma and its working.

Comment: So could anyone help?